# Can I have two Schengen visas in the same time since I lost my first one?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, international-travel, tourist-visas

I had Schengen student visa in Spain (D) but I lost it and now I want to apply with my new passport to a tourist visa for different countries in schengen zone because I can’t travel, is that possible?

Comment: Are you still a student in spain? do you have a residence permit?

Comment: I believe it **should not** be possible. If they issue you a new visa, that would be a mistake. You should tell the Spanish authorities that you lost your passport to make sure it isn't abused by a dishonest finder, anyway, you can ask them how to go about this.

Comment: I don’t have a residence permit and the Spanish authorites says they can issue me something that can only be used inside spain ( a certificate)

Comment: Revoking a lost visa and applying for a new one should not be a problem. And you would not in fact have two Schengen visas, the student (D) visa is a national visa. But there are several complications in your case. The regulations do not explicitly forbid getting a short-stay visa but, as a resident in the Schengen area, you're probably expected to secure a proper residence card from Spain instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, because you lost your passport. If the passport is found and the Schengen visa is still valid then you cannot apply for another Schengen visa.

However it is better to call and ask the country you visit under Schengen Area.

Answer (score 0):

The rule concerning overlapping Schengen visas is only valid for tourist (C) visas. What long-term (D) visas you might have at the same time is irrelevant and in fact you can be in possession of several long-term Schengen visas at the same time.

So go ahead and apply for a tourist visit.